# Reboot Ubuntu Server remotely (attack)

Tags: ubuntu-server

We set up a server for Teamspeak and Minecraft in a friend's appartment. At the moment he is not around. The server seems to have crashed, but not completely (still able to ping). I do have root, but I can't connect via Windows Remote Desktop. The FTP server is also down ("Server unexpectedly closed network connection").

How can I reboot the server? Is there a way to cause a kernel panic or something like that (last resort)?

Comment: Can you connect over SSH? Also, if the server is behind his router, then it's his router which is responding to the pings. The server might be completely crashed, or shut down.

Comment: no, putty returns the same error as filezilla

Comment: If connection attempts are all closed unexpectedly, then there's probably not much you can do without physical access to the server.

Comment: Couldn't I use some kind of DoS attack?

Comment: @Urinprobe: If you *could*, don't you think that that would be an even bigger problem than the one you're currently facing?

Comment: Not really, as the server is in a closed network, so no attacks from the outside. And it's a small network where I know all the users ;)

Comment: Do you have the MAC address of the computer?

Comment: I don't think so :/ How would that help?

Comment: @StephenP. A WoL packet probably wouldn't make it past the router from the internet.

Comment: A better solution might be to set up a watchdog, which can restart systems and/or services automatically.  Depending on the OS that you're using, it may be built into the OS.  There's also installable watchdogs.  Search for your OS and "watchdog".